# How to re-structure the existing graphql source in gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I use gatsby-source-strapi to gather some data from strapi in gatsby

i need to change the data structure and generate a new set of source for my staticquery,

how do i achieve the expected result below with gatsby graphql function? (createResolvers, sourceNode, createSchemaCustomization)

**GIVEN that i dont wanna to change the database structure**

e.g original query

```
query MyQuery {
    allStrapiAppPermissions {
        edges {
            node {
                name
                markets {
                    code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result that generate by above query

```
{
    "data": {
        "allStrapiAppPermissions": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "PERMISSION_MYACC_OVERVIEW",
                    "markets": [
                        {
                            "code": "hk"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "th"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "PERMISSION_MYACC_UPDATE",
                    "markets": [
                        {
                            "code": "hk"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

e.g expected result that i wanna to achieve

```
{
    "data": {
        "all_Concated_StrapiAppPermissions": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "markets": {"code": "hk"},
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "name": "PERMISSION_MYACC_UPDATE"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "PERMISSION_MYACC_OVERVIEW"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "node": {
                    "markets": {"code": "th"},,
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "name": "PERMISSION_MYACC_OVERVIEW"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just write a simple function that transforms one data structure into the other?

Comment: can, but i wanna ask the grahpql way

Comment: graphql is for fetching data in a **shape provided by api**, not for conversion

Comment: i mean using gatsby not graphql itself

Comment: as i mentioned, using createResolvers, sourceNode, createSchemaCustomization, have you read my question?